# clearing a notification from another par of an app

Tags: android, notifications

I have an activity that fires a notification is it possible to cancel that notification from a different activity?

is that was the notification id is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the NotificationManager and the ID to clear a notification. You can find some more details here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html